# Use Linq to read data from an online XML file

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I've been looking for a way to read specific data from an XML file in C#.

Example XML file: [here](http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=17392&typeid=2393&regionlimit=10000002&usesystem=30000142).

I'm trying to make a method that, given an id attribute (such as "17392", see example), can return the max buy price for that specific type id.

I've been looking for a couple hours, and to be honest I'm in over my head. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worked for me

```
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"MyFile.xml");
        var lv1s = from lv1 in xdoc.Descendants("type")
                   .Where(l => (string) l.Attribute("id") == "17392")
                   .Descendants("buy")
                   select (string)lv1.Element("max");


        string Result = "";
        foreach (var lv1 in lv1s)
        {
            Result = lv1.ToString();
        }
```

**Explaination:** What it does it first loads the xml file,then it loops through its descendants("**type**") where its attribute ("**id**") is **17392** as per your requirement
and from that it goes one level down to select descendants ("**buy**") and from buy it selects the **max** element.In short it just follows the structure of your tree

Comment: It works, thanks. I have absolutely no clue how, but it works anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) with LINQ to XML:

```
string url = "...";

var client = new HttpClient();
string xml = client.GetStringAsync(url).Result;

var result = XDocument.Parse(xml).Descendants("type")
    .Where(e => (string) e.Attribute("id") == "17392")
    .Descendants("buy")
    .Select(e => (string) e.Element("max"))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: It looks like System.Net.Http is no longer included in .NET. Is there any way to add it?

Comment: @Serendipity: which version of .NET you are using?

Comment: @Cuolong Le: I'm using .NET version 4

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the following [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/18/building-a-windows-phone-7-twitter-application-using-silverlight.aspx). Explained in detail.

For you requirements, you can use contains() method to filter the specific tags data with id given to the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm typing on a phone so forgive my casing and I can't see the XML structure. So I'm assuming the node with the price is called priceNode.

var xml = XDocument.Load(URL);

var q = xml.Root.Elements().First(x=> x.Attributes.Any() && x.Attribute("id") =="17392").Elements("PriceNode").Max(n=> n.Value);